# GWT Determining Row Value during Cell render

Tags: gwt, datagrid, render, cell, celltable

I'd like to determine whether an icon is used based on the value of the "row" value that is in the CellTable (or DataGrid). How do I determine that when building the Cell renderer?

```
IconCellDecorator<String> icd = new IconCellDecorator<String>(res.search(), new ClickableTextCell()) {
  @Override
  protected boolean isIconUsed(String value) {
    //value may not be unique across rows (column value), I really need the row instance here.
  }
};
```

Comment: It appears to me that I really want the decorator to take my row type, but then the ClickableTextCell won't know how to get the string value it needs. It appears I have to write a custom IconCellDecorator, but thought there was possibly a cleaner solution.

Comment: Just realized that render() has a context which gives an index and key... Thinking this might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the *row* object, you'll have to use an `IconCellDecorator<RowObject>`, and wrap or subclass the `ClickableTextCell` to extract the `String` out of the `RowObject`.

Or you could use a `CompositeCell` and `ImageResourceCell` instead of the `IconCellDecorator`.

Comment: Wrapping/subclassing ClickableTextCell looks like the awkward part. It s not really meant to handle non-text. I'll look if CompositeCell makes sense. (I've actually made my own IconDecorator that doesn't show a blank area when the icon isn't used. so might need to refactor)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to rewrite IconCellDecorator so that the getImageUsed method passes in the Context object, which gives me the row index and key. This seemed the most straightforward for specifically what I was trying to accomplish, although Thomas' answer should work as well.